# when i am trying in developer query editor console below query i am getting these error

Tags: soql

Please find the below query and please explain me the correct query.when i am trying it was showing

> unknown parsing error.

```
SELECT Count(Id), OwnerId 
FROM Task 
WHERE CreatedDate = Today 
    AND Type != 'Other Task' 
    AND OwnerId IN :taskUsers 
GROUP BY OwnerId
ORDER BY Count(Id) ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query editor does not support bind variables, thus `OwnerID in :taskUsers` would make it invalid.

Fix would be use individual owner

```
SELECT Count(Id), ownerId 
from Task 
where createdDate = Today and Type != 'Other Task' and OwnerID in ('00558000000EVMh' ,'00588000000EVMh')
group by OwnerID 
Order By Count(Id) Asc
```